# Missing kube_pod_completion metric in Prometheus

Tags: devops, prometheus, metrics

I'm running Prometheus,

```
prometheus         deployed        prometheus-22.6.6       v2.44.0
```

on Kubernetes using docker desktop 1.25.9 using Helm (version 3.11.1). I have noticed that the kube_pod_completion metric is missing from the metrics exposed by Prometheus.

I have already installed and configured Prometheus using

```
helm install prometheus prometheus-community/prometheus --set prometheus-node-exporter.hostRootFsMount.enabled=false
```

from the Prometheus Community repository. I have verified that the kube-state-metrics service is running and accessible.

However, when I check the available metrics in Prometheus, I don't see the kube_pod_completion metric listed.

[image]
Here is my Prometheus configuration in the values.yaml file:

```
scrape_configs:
  - job_name: prometheus
    static_configs:
      - targets:
        - localhost:9090
  - job_name: 'spring'
    metrics_path: '/actuator/prometheus'
    scrape_interval: 3s
    static_configs:
      - targets: ['spring-consumer-service:8087']
        labels:
          application: 'consumer-app'
```